# Why is mongo saving changes even though the transaction fails?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, transactions

**Code:**

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession();
session.startTransaction();
try {
  const model = mongoose.model("cars");
  const document = { _id: "6059edf7fc81428fcc0b5c33" };
  await model.create(document);
  await model.create(document); // illegal duplicate key

  await session.commitTransaction();
  session.endSession();
} catch (error) {
  await session.abortTransaction();
  session.endSession();
}
```

**Expected behavior:**
I expect the whole operation to fail, with no entries inserted into the databse

**Actual behavior:**
the commitTransaction() is not called, since the second create() fails; the abortTransaction() is called, but after the code is executed, the database has the first entry.

Seems like this question describes the same thing, but no answers:
[Why does some documents get saved in mongoose transactions eventhough the transaction fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63102003/why-does-some-documents-get-saved-in-mongoose-transactions-eventhough-the-transa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to explicitly pass the session to every operation you want to be part of the session.

Here is an example from the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html) :

> ```
> session.startTransaction();
>
> // This `create()` is part of the transaction because of the `session`
> // option.
> await Customer.create([{ name: 'Test' }], { session: session });
> ```

Applying the same to your code:

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession();
session.startTransaction();
try {
  const model = mongoose.model("cars");
  const document = { _id: "6059edf7fc81428fcc0b5c33" };
  await model.create(document, {session: session});
  await model.create(document, {session: session}); // illegal duplicate key

  await session.commitTransaction();
  session.endSession();
} catch (error) {
  await session.abortTransaction();
  session.endSession();
}
```

Comment: Indeed this is what I was looking for.
Any idea how to also use the session in the schema validator function? I posted this question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66768458/how-to-get-mongoose-session-in-mongoose-schema-validator